# Button Click Event Generalization

Tags: c#, button, windows-forms-designer

How do i get a text of the button, when i click it, in the listbox without defining event for all button. How to generalize it.

[image]

Comment: You have to add event handlers for every button.  What's wrong with that?

Comment: I just posted a few button. These are about 52 buttons. Don't you think it would be long....

Comment: You can have all buttons handled by the same method, getting the text of the button from the sender parameter.

Comment: @ziakhan -- well, then see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is loop through the buttons on your form programmatically and add event handlers for each one.

Put this in your form's constructor:

```
foreach (var ctrl in this.Controls)
{
    if (ctrl is Button)
    {
        ((Button) ctrl).Click += MainForm_Click;
    }
}
```

And here's your event handler:

```
void MainForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(((Button) sender).Text);
}
```

Equalsk's suggestion is a good one: if you have other buttons on your form that you don't wish to be part of this behavior, you can put the buttons that you *do* want in a panel or other control on your form.  Then you'd just change the `foreach` in your constructor to this:

```
foreach (var ctrl in this.panel1.Controls)
```

Comment: OP, it might be worth putting these buttons in a `Panel` or `GroupBox` and iterating the children of said control so you only affect the correct buttons. As it stands if you iterate the parent form you might have other buttons where you _don't_ want this handler.

Answer (score 0):

In the code-behind, you use a for-loop to assign the same event handler for all buttons. That event handler will get a `sender` passed as first parameter, which is the button you clicked on. Typecast that to a `Button` and you can access its text.

Comment: So...basically my answer but without examples.

Comment: @rory.ap So...basically your answer but with an explanation. ;)

Comment: @Servy -- Fixed that!